# How highlight a text contain a link in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink, highlight

In Rails, highlight some keywords in text is easy, just use `highlight()` view helper, but if the text contains some links, that's a problem, after highlight, the link dismiss, but in fact I want reserve them.

Example:

```
pry(main)> text = "stackoverflow is awesome"
=> "stackoverflow is awesome"
pry(main)> helper.highlight(text, ['over', 'awe'])
=> "stack<mark>over</mark>flow is <mark>awe</mark>some"
```

This is what I want.

But if the text contains a link:

```
[20] pry(main)> text = "<p><a href=\"https://www.google.com\">google</a></p>"
=> "<p><a href=\"https://www.google.com\">google</a></p>"
[21] pry(main)> helper.highlight(text, 'goo')
=> "<p><mark>goo</mark>gle</p>"
```

Then the `<a>` tag is gone. I want to get `"<p><a href="https://www.google.com"><mark>goo</mark>gle</a></p>"`

How can I keep the `<a>` tag when highlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `helper.highlight(text, ['over', 'awe'], sanitize: false)`.